# Restrict user from accessing webpage + Incorrect username/password alert

Tags: php

I'm using php but without database.

When I log in with the wrong username/password, it shows "Incorrect username/password" which is correct.

However, when I access the other webpages without logging in, it also shows "Incorrect username/password" instead of "You must be logged in to access this page".

```
<?php
$username = "admin";
$password = "its30305";

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['username])){
    echo "<h1>Welcome ".$_SESSION['username]."</h1>";
}

else{
    if($_POST['username] == $username && $_POST['password'] == $password){
         $_SESSION['username] = $username;
         echo "<script>location.href='mainmenu.php'</script>;
    }

    elif($_POST['username] != $username || $_POST['password'] != $password){
         echo "<script>alert('Username/Password incorrect!')</script>";
         echo "<script>location.href='login.php'</script>;
    }

    elif(!isset($_SESSION['access]){
         echo "<script>alert('You must log in to access this page')</script>";
         echo "<script>location.href='login.php'</script>;
    }
```

?>

Comment: You need to post your code here, as code and not as an image.

Comment: Welcome to SO, i'll suggest you to read [mcve] before asking

Comment: The complement of $username == 'username' && $password == 'password' is $username != 'username' || $password != 'password

Comment: @jeroen sorry, it's my first time using this. just added my code.

Comment: In your code remember that you have to put session_start in the first line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't validate login like that but if you want to know about the problem,
check this line:

```
else if(!isset($_SESSION['access']){
```

Check $_SESSION['access'] before $_POST and you shouldn't have that problem anymore:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['access']){
     //Need login to access this page
}else if($_POST['username'] == $username && $_POST['password'] == $password){
     //Wrong username or password
}else if ...
```

*I strongly recommend to change structure of your code:*

**Use PHP forwarding instead of JavaScript forwarding**

If you want to forward to the login page when user doesn't have permission to the page, use `header` like this:

```
header('location: /login.php');
die();
```

Always terminate the current script after forward by using `die()` or `exit()`.

**Check if $_POST key is set before using it**

make sure $_POST set before, For example:

```
isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username'] == $username
```

**Don't store raw password in your codes**

Always store hash password, no matter you are using database or not. If you want to find out what is your password hash you can find it out with:

```
password_hash("its30305", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

and you can use it in your code:

```
$username = 'admin';
$password = '$2y$10$ZSCf.Nlma2mBrKetjqnEB.sdWcBiGJoByhPxwo9wCW8Nvz5Zc7Omm';  //Result of password_hash("its30305", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Read about [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

**Use password_verify to verify your password**

You can verify password with password_verify like this:

```
isset($_POST['password']) && password_verify($_POST['password'],$password)
```

Read about [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

**Show proper message in login page**

If you want to show to the user, you need to login to see the page content, you can set a $_SESSION['login_message'] before `header()`, and check that session in login page. If it is set show proper message on login page and then unset the session. For example:

```
$_SESSION['login_message'] = 1; //user need to login to see the content
header('location: /login.php');
die();
```

on login.php:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['login_message'])){
   switch ($_SESSION['login_message']){
        case 1:
           echo 'Need to login to see the page.';
           break;
        case 2:
           echo 'Wrong username or password.';
           break;
   }
   //saw the message, not need it anymore!
   unset($_SESSION['login_message']);
}
```